# `=>` in scala function literal

Tags: function, scala

What does the second `=>` mean in the following function literal ?

```
val result: () => Int = () => throw new RuntimeException
result: () => Int = <function0>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In type declaration `val result: () => Int` it is just an easy way to declare a function type:

`() => Int` is the same as `Function0[Int]`

Here `() => throw new RuntimeException` it's a function declaration and `=>` separates arguments from body. Therefore it's declaration of an *anonymous* function with no arguments and body  `throw new RuntimeException`. It's equivalent to:

```
def f() = throw new RuntimeException
```

Comment: It's actually a function that takes `()` as an argument, instead of no arguments. Think of the difference between `def g(f: () => Int)` and `def h(f: => Int)`. The first `f` takes `()` as argument, the second would take none.

Comment: @Chirlo that's wrong, those are two different things, `() => Int` is a function which takes no argument and returns an Int, `f: => Int` means that f is lazily evaluated, but it's definately not a function.

Comment: @Ende, if you take the `result` on his sample, you still have to apply it like `result()` in order to evaluate it. Actually both `f` on my comment get compiled to `Function0[Int]`, but from the source code semantics I think my observation is more precise

Comment: @Chirlo, this function doesn't take any args and `()` says about it. And both your examples `g` and `h` are instances of `Function1`. Also in OP example you can call `result()` - it's just a function call, but you can't pass it `()`: `result(())` - will not compile.

Comment: @ka4eli , `g` and `h` are `Function1`, I was talking about the `f` they're passed as parameters , which are both `Function0`.

Answer (score 1):

First `=>` means that type of `val` is `function` which apply no parameters and return `Int`.

Second `=>` is divider between parameter list `()` and function's body `throw new RuntimeException`